Flutter How to combine FlowBuilder with GoRouter
I am trying to get authenticated routing working. My  plan was to seperate the authenticated routing logic into FlowBuilder, since this seems more convenient with top level authentication states.
An object literal to represent the routing plan:
FlowBuilder: {
  unauthenticated: loginPage,
  authenticated: {
    GoRouter: {
      '/': dashboardPage,
      '/settings': settingsPage,
    }
  }
}

I tried multiple solutions but kept getting into issues like?

Needs multiple MaterialApps, which is unrecommended? Since you need to pass MaterialApp.router.
Gives TextDirectionality errors.
Gives MaterialLocalizations error

Unfinished sample of what I have now:
Main:
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await initializeFirebase();

  final authenticationRepository = AuthenticationRepository();
  await authenticationRepository.user.first;

  runApp(RootApp(
    authenticationRepository: authenticationRepository,
  ));
}

// create empty async function
Future<void> initializeFirebase() async {
  // initialize Firebase
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  // if the app is running in debug mode
  if (kDebugMode) {
    try {
      // use the Firebase Auth emulator
      //  FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator('localhost', 8080);
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator('localhost', 9099);
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore the error
    }
  }
}

RootApp:
class RootApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const RootApp({
    super.key,
    // required this.router,
    required AuthenticationRepository authenticationRepository,
  }) : _authenticationRepository = authenticationRepository;

  // final GoRouter router;
  final AuthenticationRepository _authenticationRepository;
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RepositoryProvider.value(
      value: _authenticationRepository,
      child: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => AppBloc(
          authenticationRepository: _authenticationRepository,
        ),
        child: AuthenticationFlow(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

LoginScreen:
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static Page page() => const MaterialPage(child: LoginScreen());
  static String routeName = '/login';

  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Placeholder(),
    );
  }
}

DashboardScreen:
class DashboardScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static Page page() => const MaterialPage(child: DashboardScreen());
  static String routeName = '/dashboard';

  const DashboardScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Dashboard'),
      ),
      body: Placeholder(),
    );
  }
}

